# CDN scripts not enqueuing in WordPress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, bootstrap-4, cdn

I'm trying to enqueue scripts & styles from CDN in Wordpress so I can use this JSfiddle within the footer of my code:

https://jsfiddle.net/wcepbL45/

I can see the 6 scripts are loading in my Page Source, but the JSfiddle I'm trying to embed in the footer isn't working.

I am guessing some of the new scripts are clashing with the original ones, or do I need to be enqueuing these in my footer.php file?

So atm, my functions.php has this code:

```
<?php

function load_stylesheets()
{
wp_register_style('bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css',
    array(), false, 'all');
wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap');


    wp_register_style('style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
    array(), false, 'all');
wp_enqueue_style('style');



}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_stylesheets'); 




function include_jquery()
{
wp_deregister_script('jquery');

wp_enqueue_script('jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery-3.1.3.min.js', '', 1, true);



add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'jquery');
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'include_jquery');



function loadjs()
{
wp_register_script('customjs', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/scripts.js', '', 1, true);
wp_enqueue_script('customjs');

}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'loadjs');



// Next 6 styles are new (I can see them when i view page source, but I think they are clashing with something, as the JSfiddle I'm trying to input isnt working.

wp_register_style( 'Bootstrap', 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css' );
wp_enqueue_style('Bootstrap');


wp_register_style( 'Bootstrap_Theme', 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css' );
wp_enqueue_style('Bootstrap_Theme');


wp_register_style( 'Bootstrap_Slider', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/9.8.0/css/bootstrap-slider.min.css' );
wp_enqueue_style('Bootstrap_Slider');


wp_register_script( 'jQuery', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js', null, null, true );
wp_enqueue_script('jQuery');


wp_register_script( 'Bootstrap', 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js', null, null, true );
wp_enqueue_script('Bootstrap');

wp_register_script( 'Bootstrap_Slider', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/9.8.0/bootstrap-slider.min.js', null, null, true );
wp_enqueue_script('Bootstrap_Slider');

//
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Any particular reason of why the last 6 scripts are outside those "wp_enqueue_scripts" functions? Beside that, you should try prefixing the handle with something like "thats-me". If you don't have any weird cache/cache setting you should see those scripts inside your source code

Comment: hey Diego, I tried them inside, but it still wasn't making the range slider work, it did tweak the font size + hyperlink colours. So I am guessing these new bootstrap scripts and styles + the jquery I am trying to load (to make the range slider work) is clashing with the original ones?

Answer (score 0):

Multiple mistakes here, You should restrict the use of your scripts to everything but the admin panel. You're not checking if the CDN is actually working, and you have no fallback. `get_template_directory_uri()` should not be used for the loading the `style.css` file, instead use `get_stylesheet_uri()`. You're using multiple functions for no reason and loading. your call for `wp_register_style` and `wp_register_style` are outside any functions.

I will just paste what i'm using to load and enqueue scripts and style, feel free to copy pasta! Hope this will help you, don't forget to thumbs up the answer if it does.

```
<?php add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_scripts' );
function theme_scripts() {
  if ( ! is_admin() ) {

    /**
    * Register then enqueue bootstrap bundle js (Bootstrap 5.x required)
    *
    * Check if CDN's url is valid, if not return fallback
    */
    $test_bootstrap_bundle_js = @fopen( 'https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/5.0.0-alpha1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js', 'r' );
    if ( $test_bootstrap_bundle_js !== false ) {
      wp_register_script( 'bootstrap_bundle_js', '//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/5.0.0-alpha1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js' );
    } else {
      wp_register_script( 'bootstrap_bundle_js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js' );
    };
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap_bundle_js' );


    /**
    * Register then enqueue bootstrap css (Bootstrap 5.x required)
    *
    * Check if CDN's url is valid, if not return fallback
    */
    $test_bootstrap_css = @fopen( 'https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/5.0.0-alpha1/css/bootstrap.min.css', 'r' );
    if ( $test_bootstrap_css !== false ) {
      wp_register_style( 'bootstrap_css', '//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/5.0.0-alpha1/css/bootstrap.min.css' );
    } else {
      wp_register_style( 'bootstrap_css', get_stylesheet_uri() . '/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css' );
    };
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap_css' );

    /**
    * Register then enqueue style css
    */
    wp_register_style( 'style_css', get_stylesheet_uri(), array( 'bootstrap_css' ) );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style_css' );

  };
}; ?>
```

**EDIT 1:** Read more about the `wp_enqueue_script` @ https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/

**EDIT 2:** Bootstrap 5 as a range plug and play component @ https://v5.getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/range/ (same for Bootstrap 4)

**EDIT 3:** When you enqueue your scripts you can set up dependencies restricting the load and enqueue of your script

```
<?php
    /**
    * Register then enqueue script js
    */
    wp_register_script( 'script_js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/script.js', array( 'bootstrap_bundle_js', 'jquery_js' ) );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'script_js' ); ?>
```

Inside the `wp_register_script` we specify an array of script to load our new script after `array( 'bootstrap_bundle_js', 'jquery_js' )`. It uses the handles defined upon registering the style/script `wp_register_script( 'script_js', ...` here `'script_js'` is the handle.

Comment: Hmm, isn't that an overkill to check the URL for every request that hits the site? like that u're going to waste so much time waiting for those fopens if something goes slow. Just my 2 cents

Comment: Well this is part of the best practices. Waste so much time? This one is funny, try it and tell me if you waste so much time. You can learn more about @fopen here https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_fopen.asp . We are pretty much opening the requested file (which we would do anw) and if the read is possible (true or false pretty much) then we load it else we fallback.

Comment: Im just saying that if i had to do that i would keep it cached for a while, i don't think it's necessary to keep checking on every request if the url is still there. Or at least, that approach is really pessimistic :P not intenteded to offend anyone

Comment: No problem was just sharing science, in any cas and at the end of the day, you're the dev, and it's your project!

Comment: Hey, how would I write this for my 10 CDN's (below). And are any of these clashing with each other? For example, I have 2 versions of bootstrap.min.css , and 2 different jquery libraries I am trying to load - 3.1.3 and 2.1.1

Comment: '/css/bootstrap.min.css'

'/style.css'

'/js/jquery-3.1.3.min.js'

'/js/scripts.js'

'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css'
'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css'

'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/9.8.0/css/bootstrap-slider.min.css'

'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js'

'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js'
'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/9.8.0/bootstrap-slider.min.js'

Comment: Gave you a short example to the approach, see new answer

Answer (score 0):

In response to your last comment, we can do something like this:

**For your JS scripts:**

(1) `jquery.min.js`,
**eg:** `wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery_js', '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js' );`

(2) `bootstrap.min.js` with dependency towards (1),
**eg:** `wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap_js', '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js', array( 'jquery_js' ) );`

(3) `bootstrap-slider.min.js` with dependency towards (1) & (2),
**eg:** `wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap_slider_js', '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/9.8.0/bootstrap-slider.min.js', array( 'jquery_js', 'bootstrap_js' ) );`

(4) `script.js` with dependency towards (1) & (2) & (3),
**eg:** `wp_enqueue_script( 'script_js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/script.js', array( 'jquery_js', 'bootstrap_js', 'bootstrap_slider_js' ) );`

**For your CSS scripts:**

(1) `bootstrap.min.css`, **eg:** (same here but with `wp_enqueue_style`)

(2) `bootstrap-slider.css` with dependency towards (1),

(3) `style.css` with dependency towards (1) & (2),